# JavaFX code doesn't run after closing VScode and open it again

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I made a simple javaFx project yesterday and it worked and ran fine, but today when I tried to run it gave me an error :(
And it happened again with another project today.
Even though I added the JavaFx libraries and the configuration correctly.

I think the problem happens when I try to run the program after I close the VScode and open it again or maybe after turning the laptop off or something.

This is my code:

The first class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FxmlDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Hyperlink si_forgotPass;

    @FXML
    private Button si_loginBtn;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane si_loginForm;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField si_password;

    @FXML
    private TextField si_username;

    @FXML
    private Button side_createBtn;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane side_form;

    @FXML
    private TextField su_answer;

    @FXML
    private PasswordField su_password;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> su_question;

    @FXML
    private Button su_signUpBtn;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane su_signUpForm;

    @FXML
    private TextField su_username;

    @FXML
    private Button side_alreadyHave;

    public void switchForm(ActionEvent event) {

        TranslateTransition slider = new TranslateTransition();

        if (event.getSource() == side_createBtn) {
            slider.setNode(side_form);
            slider.setToX(300);
            slider.setDuration(Duration.seconds(.5));
            slider.setOnFinished((ActionEvent e) -> {
                side_alreadyHave.setVisible(true);
                side_createBtn.setVisible(false);
            });

            slider.play();

        } else if (event.getSource() == side_alreadyHave) {
            slider.setNode(side_form);
            slider.setToX(0);
            slider.setDuration(Duration.seconds(.5));
            slider.setOnFinished((ActionEvent e) -> {
                side_alreadyHave.setVisible(false);
                side_createBtn.setVisible(true);
            });

            slider.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
       
    }

}
```

the second class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CafeShopManagmentSystem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\nsoor\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\CafeProject\\CafeShopManagementSystem\\src\\FxmlDocumentController.java"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

the configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "CafeShopManagmentSystem",
            "projectName": "CafeShopManagementSystem_b45da6ad",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/java/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        },
        {

            "type": "java",
            "name": "FxmlDocumentController",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "FxmlDocumentController",
            "projectName": "CafeShopManagementSystem_b45da6ad",
            "vmArgs": "--module-path \"C:/java/lib\" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
        }
    ]
}
```

the error:

```
PS C:\Users\nsoor\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\CafeProject\CafeShopManagementSystem>  & 'C:\Users\nsoor\scoop\apps\oraclejdk\18.0.2.1\bin\java.exe' '@C:\Users\nsoor\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_6r3pd7ec9uu67bxxyvokb3rac.argfile' 'CafeShopManagmentSystem' 
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3369)
        at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3332)
        at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3300)
        at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3272)
        at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3248)
        at javafx.fxml@21.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3241)
        at CafeShopManagmentSystem.start(CafeShopManagmentSystem.java:11)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@21.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application CafeShopManagmentSystem
```

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post error messages as text, formatted as code. The error message indicates a problem with your setup, either with your `module.java` file if this is a modular application or with your module path or classpath. Problems "magically" appearing after restarting your IDE seem unlikely, at best. I recommend following the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ for setting up JavaFX projects. Other than that there really isn't nearly enough information in the question to help diagnose any issues.

Comment: The new error you posted (which is a completely different error to the one of which you posted an image in the original question) is caused by the path to the FXML being incorrectly specified. This is no surprise, since you are providing a file path to a method which is expecting a resource path.